# How small need it be to approximate integral as one area of product of initial value times length.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right), a(t) \text{ is scalar}$$

How small need $\Delta t$ be to approximate $$\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right)$$ as $$a(t)\Delta t$$ [ Just one product of initial value times length. Not as a sum of such as in Riemann Sum.]

I question myself and conclude 4 possibilities.

a. I need $\Delta t << a(t)$

b. I need $\Delta t << \frac{da(t)}{dt}$

c. I need $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$

d. I cannot do that. Even $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ does not allow me to do such approximation. I think that, say $a$ is a constant decreasing function with slope of 45 degree. Doing such approximation always lead to double of the actual integral area.

Am I reasoning correct or when is the condition ($a$ differentiable, analytic (a can be complex)?)that I can do such approximation?

Answer (score 1):

No matter what continuous function $a$ is, there is small enough $\Delta t$ to make this a reasonable approximation. However, there are "arbitrarily bad" continuous functions that need arbitrarily small $\Delta t$ to make this reasonable. A class of situations where you can quantify this is when $a$ is continuously differentiable near $a$; in this case this approximation is reasonable provided that $\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2$ (the leading order term of the error) is much smaller than $a(t) \Delta t$.

Comment: Thanks. But as I write in d. If the function always has a slope of 45 degree but we do it as a square, there is always 50% error. Am I correct?

Comment: I think you mean that you have $a(t)=1-\frac{t}{\Delta t}$ and you are noticing that this approximation gives an area of $\Delta t$ while the true area is $\Delta t/2$. And that's correct. But in this case my criterion fails: $\frac{da}{dt} \Delta t^2$ and $a(t) \Delta t$ are of the same order because $\frac{da}{dt}$ is huge. That's the sort of thing I meant when referring to "arbitrarily bad" continuous functions.

Comment: In fact this situation is actually a bit worse because as you can see, you are choosing a different continuous function for each $\Delta t$. If you don't do that (i.e. if you pick a continuous function and then send $\Delta t$ to zero) *eventually* this approximation becomes accurate. But the $\Delta t$ that you need may be very very small before that happens.

Comment: I think my thought is for example $a(t) = 1 - t$. It has a downward slope of 45 degree. Say $t = 0$ So $a(0) = 1$. Say $\Delta t = 0.0001$. I have $a(0)\Delta t = 0.0001$, but $\left(\int_{0}^{0+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right) = 0.00005$.

Comment: Is the case in the bad case? Thanks.

Comment: You're mistaken in your calculation, in fact; in this case $\Delta t$ is small enough that the region whose area is described by your integral is not a triangle but rather a trapezoid, which is very nearly a rectangle. (More specifically, it is a rectangle with a tiny triangle cut out of it.) For it to be a triangle for $\Delta t$ that small you need to make the slope much larger: $-10000$ instead of $-1$. With $-10000$ you would have the problem that you mentioned, but now $1-10000t$ is a "bad" function for $\Delta t=0.0001$. On the other hand it would be fine for, say, $\Delta t=0.00000001$.

Comment: Yes, I am wrong. Thanks. You mentioned that $\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2$ is the leading term of error. Is there function $a$ such that  $\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2$ is similiar or even smaller that other terms in the error, say $\frac{1}{3!}(\frac{da}{dt}(t))^2 \Delta t^3$. You mentioned that $\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2 << a(t) \Delta t$ Does that mean $\Delta t<<\frac{a(t)}{\frac{da}{dt}(t)}$? All in all, if I have $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$, can I replace the integral with the square even with bad function? Thanks.

Comment: For good relative error you need exactly $\Delta t \ll \left | \frac{a}{a'} \right |$, that's right. When I say leading term I mean that for sufficiently small $\Delta t$, the other terms describing the error are far smaller. So in fact one cannot merely control everything by $\Delta t \ll \left | \frac{a}{a'} \right |$, instead you really need to control everything by something like $\left | \frac{a}{\max |a'|} \right |$ or similar. But in practice $\left | \frac{a}{a'} \right |$ usually suffices.

Comment: Thanks. What if $a$ is not a real scalar, but a square matrix, say 2 by 2, or a complex number? Do i need your condition for every element $a_{ii}$, or is there another condition in terms of matrix?

Comment: You can give conditions in terms of entries or in terms of some norm of the matrix. Either way is fine (there is no impact on the convergence in the end from what measurement you use).

Comment: which matrix norm do you suggest? Some may not produce accurate result. The values of $\frac{|a|}{|a'|}$ depends a lot on the choice of norm.

Comment: If you take the ratio of norms of $|a|$ and $|a'|$ then it does not matter, as long is the norm is actually a norm.

Comment: Can you tell me how to derive the leading error term $\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2$? It seems that it is the taylor expansion of $a$ only, but not of $\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right)$

Comment: but i could have  it where a′(t)=0 at a specific point tt but the higher derivatives are not necessarily zero at that point.